# How to implement solidity bitwise in Golang

Tags: go, solidity, bitwise-operators

Code in UniswapV3 Solidity contract [TickBitmap](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/TickBitmap.sol)

```
uint256 mask = ~((1 << bitPos) - 1);
```

How to implement this solidity caculation in golang?

I had founded some example code in Golang:

```
    a := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(66), nil)
    a.Sub(a, big.NewInt(1))
    b := bitwiseNot(a)

func bitwiseNot(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    mask := new(big.Int).SetBit(new(big.Int), 256, 1)
    result := new(big.Int).Xor(x, mask)
    return result
}
```

When I Test code on Remix, try bitpos=66, Remix Output:

```
uint256: mask 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039383797031618291433472
```

Golang Output:

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039531370984207967846399
```

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, the `~` operator performs bitwise `NOT` operation, and the `<<` operator performs bitwise `left shift`. The expression `(1 << bitPos) - 1` calculates a number that has all bits set to 1 up to the bitPos-th bit. Then, the bitwise `NOT (~)` inverts all bits.

In Golang, you can perform similar bitwise operations using the `math/big` package. However, you have to be careful with the bitwise NOT operation because it's not directly supported for `big.Int` in the standard library.

Here's how you can implement the Solidity calculation in Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    bitPos := 66

    // Calculate (1 << bitPos) - 1
    one := big.NewInt(1)
    bitPosBig := big.NewInt(int64(bitPos))
    mask := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), bitPosBig, nil)
    mask.Sub(mask, one)

    // Perform bitwise NOT
    maskNot := bitwiseNot(mask)

    fmt.Println("Golang Output:", maskNot.String())
}

func bitwiseNot(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    // Create a mask with all bits set to 1
    mask := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(256), nil)
    mask.Sub(mask, big.NewInt(1))

    // XOR with mask to perform bitwise NOT
    result := new(big.Int).Xor(x, mask)
    return result
}
```

Here is [playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/5T_CD5ialqa)

**Note** I've used a 256-bit mask for the bitwise NOT operation, which is consistent with the 256-bit integers in Solidity.

**EDIT**

Here is the difference between two approaches,

*Your Original Method*

```
mask := new(big.Int).SetBit(new(big.Int), 256, 1)
```

In this method, you're creating a new big.Int and setting the bit at position 256 to 1. This essentially creates a big.Int where all bits are 0 except for the one at position 256. This is not a mask with all bits set to 1; it's a number with only one bit set to 1.

*The Method I Suggested:*

```
allOnes := new(big.Int).Sub(new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(256), nil), big.NewInt(1))
```

In this method, I'm using the formula 2^256 - 1 to create a `big.Int` where all `256` bits are set to 1. Specifically,  2^256 is a number where the 257th bit is 1 and all other bits are 0. When you subtract 1 from it, you flip all the lower 256 bits to 1, creating a mask where all 256 bits are set to 1.

So, the key difference is that the method I suggested actually creates a `big.Int` with all 256 bits set to 1, which is what you need for the bitwise NOT operation to match the Solidity behavior.

Comment: It works! Thanks. But what's the different between two function to `Create a mask with all bits set to 1`